# Drawing image with gradient tint and round corners

Tags: android, android-layout, android-canvas, android-drawable, android-bitmap

I'm trying to set a background on a view, which should be an image with a single rounded corner and a gradient tint overlayed

I feel like I'm close, I'm just missing the rounded corner. I have made a minimal working example project here: https://github.com/RandomStuffAndCode/AndroidCanvas

From https://github.com/RandomStuffAndCode/AndroidCanvas/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/randomcodeandstuff/androidcanvas/MainActivity.java :

```
    RoundedBitmapDrawable dr = RoundedBitmapDrawableFactory.create(getResources(), src);
    dr.setCornerRadius(convertToPixels(context, CORNER_RADIUS));
    Bitmap drBitmap = drawableToBitmap(dr);
    Paint drPaint = new Paint();
    drPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
    drPaint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN));
    canvas.drawBitmap(drBitmap, 0,0,drPaint);
```

This obviously gives me 4 rounded corners instead of just 1. I considered drawing a rectangle on top of the other rounded corners, but because of the gradient overlay this does not look good.

How do i get rid of the 3 other rounded corners? Screenshot of the code here:[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 1):

If you're targeting API level 21+, a possible option would be to use a normal ImageView, but set an [ViewOutlineProvider](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewOutlineProvider.html) on it.  The Outline you provide will probably have to be the [convexPath](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Outline.html#setConvexPath(android.graphics.Path)) option, so you'd have to tinker with that for your specific use-case.